# Finding hardware details for USB keydrive?

Tags: windows, usb-storage

I use [Speccy](http://www.piriform.com/speccy) on Windows to find what hardware is installed on a PC, but when it comes to USB keydrives, it doesn't tell much:

```
Device Kind: USB storage
Device Name: Disk drive
Comment: Audio Player USB Device
Location: Location 0
Driver: Date 7-1-2001, Version  5.1.2535.0, File    C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\disk.sys
```

I was wondering if someone knew of a utility that would return useful infos such as the manufacturer and the model number?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I used to use Chip Genius under Windows since some years ago.
http://www.mydigit.cn/chipgenius.htm

The site has a screenshot image, chipset manufactuerer is the 6th line in the second textbox, and the 7th line is the chipset model.

Comment: Thanks for the info. As expected, one of the files in the ZIP contained a virus (China...), but the application itself seems OK.

Comment: perhaps, search by keyword for another download, btw, you can boot a Linux liveUSB or liveCD, with lsusb -vvv, you can see exactly the information you need. regards.

Comment: Thanks. I did think about booting up with a Linux USB keydrive, but was curious if there were any good utilies for Windows.